# @ManyToMany for database view

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a view for some data which contains two columns (id, error_id). Mapping for this view looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ERRORCODES_V", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "prod", referencedColumnName = "prod"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =  "error_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<ProdEntity> errorCodes;
```

After I try to execute hql using criteria I got exception `Found shared references to a collection errorCodes`. The same mapping works fine for normal table. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

`Found shared references to a collection errorCodes`, it means that you are trying to add more than one reference of objects that points to same memory location.